# When you cure a zombie-villager, do they retain their levels/mastery?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have leveled a set of villagers in my world, and now I want to lower the cost of the purchases by zombifying, then subsequently curing them. However, I don't want to waste time and emeralds if they do end up losing the experience they have when zombified.

Minecraft Java Edition 1.16

Comment: For those who do not know, you can cure zombie villagers by splashing a weakness potion on them, then feeding them a golden apple. They will start shaking, and 5 minutes after they will be cured with lower costs of trades.

Comment: I advise to set the difficulty to Hard to make sure the villagers get converted, in other difficulties, there is a chance for the villager to die instead of being converted to a zombie.

Comment: @fasterthanlight In particular, on Normal - 50%, on Easy that chance is 100%, One more factor why "Easy is the real Hard".

Comment: Are there any other reasons?

Comment: @12rhombiingridwnocorners: You mean for "easy is the real hard"? Big slimes spawn rarely = reduced slime farm efficiency. Zombified piglin spawn rate from portals vastly reduced = passive overworld gold and XP farms much worse. Less phantoms = harder to get membranes. Idle wither doesn't shoot - some wither-based farms broken. Skeleton horses chance much smaller. Raid farms nearly useless (mobs with best drops don't spawn),

Comment: ah, so only pretty much for the high-level players who truly know what they're doing, easy mode is more bothersome, correct? well that makes sense, doesn't it? you always need to sacrifice some flexibility and freedom if you want something to be easier to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they retain their trades if they have been traded with. However, their costs for buying or selling will be significantly diminished. If you did not trade with the villager, then the villager will reset its trades.